# SMS SendLog relation to Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms

If I understand correctly this mean that there is no way for us to resolve what Journey the SMS in a send log relates to?

What do we get in the SMSJobID and SMSTriggeredSendID columns? I see that it is not unique per row (SMS)? Can it be matched up to anything else in the system?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

So this isn't in the send log (but you could add a custom field) By the [SMSmessagetracking dataview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=0) has the following fields:

- JBActivityID Unique identifier for the journey activity the message
  was deployed from
- JBDefinitionID   Unique identifier for the journey a message was
  deployed from

Comment: Adding a custom field in SendLog through journey requires adding an AMPScript code to each SMS activity in order to populate it, right? I am not sure this would be a way to go for my current customer. The other option could be feasible, thanks, but then the question is what is the use of the SMS Sendlog good for anyway?